# Ionic: $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/') not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, navigation, angular-ui-router

I am having some trouble with Angular navigation in Ionic framework. 
I have set two pages (states) and the app is supposed to show the first state when it is opened. However, the **$urlRouterProvider.otherwise** is not working *(I think that's the problem, at least)*. 

I have followed the [oficial documentation](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionNavView/) and some [tutorials](http://www.gajotres.net/ionic-framework-tutorial-8-page-navigation/) but nothing made it work. Can you please help me?

```js
var app = angular.module('famousguess', ['ionic', 'ui.router'])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 
 $stateProvider
   .state('welcome', {
  url: '/',
  templateUrl: 'views/welcome.html',
  controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
   })
   .state('grid', {
  url: '/grid/:gridid',
  templateUrl: 'views/grid.html',
  controller: 'GridCtrl'
   });
   
 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});

app.controller('WelcomeCtrl', function ($scope, $state) {
 
}

app.controller('GridCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $ionicHistory) {
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Famous Guess</title>

    <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- IF using Sass (run gulp sass first), then uncomment below and remove the CSS includes above
    <link href="css/ionic.app.css" rel="stylesheet">
    -->

    <!-- ionic/angularjs js -->
    <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>

    <!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
 
    <!-- your app's js -->
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="famousguess" id="wrapper">
  
 <ion-nav-bar class="bar-energized">
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-clear">
    <i class="ion-arrow-left-c"></i> Back
  </ion-nav-back-button>
 </ion-nav-bar>
 
 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


 
  </body>
</html>
```

And here goes my template (**views/home.html**)

```
<ion-view view-title="welcome">
      <ion-content scroll="false" class="box-energized">

        <h1 id="logo">Famous Guess?</h1>

        <a nav-transition="android" href="#/grid/1">
            <button class="button button-block button-royal">
              Start!
            </button>
        </a>

        <button class="button icon-left button-block button-positive ion-social-facebook">
            Connect to Facebook
        </button>

      </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you have used a wrong template in config

```
$stateProvider
      .state('welcome', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'views/home.html',
        controller: 'WelcomeCtrl'
      })
      .state('grid', {
        url: '/grid/:gridid',
        templateUrl: 'views/grid.html',
        controller: 'GridCtrl'
      });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
});
```

i think the above will work !! you have loaded the wrong template file in tempalateurl

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure if that was the problem because I started all again and it worked. So the problem was a typo, probably this one you pointed.